# Какой нужно использовать псевдокласс CSS?

Tags: css

Есть [сайт](http://evolutionnailspanj.brandivo.com/), на котором есть раздел "TESTIMONIALS" (нужно прокрутить почти в самый низ). Мне нужно выбрать второй отзыв в CSS (картинку, заголовок h5 с классом "h5" и текст с классом "testimonials"). Как мне это сделать? Пробовал **:nth-child(even)** и **:nth-of-type(2)**, не безрезультатно!

Если написать вот так:

```
.testimonials:nth-of-type(1){
    font-size: 53px !important;
    color: lightgray;   
}
```

То почему-то шрифт 53 пикселя становиться у всех трех отзывов!

Comment: если вам нужно выбрать именно второй блок (а не каждый второй как предложили ниже), то используйте такой селектор в css:

`.avia-testimonial-wrapper:nth-child(2) .testimonials {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно не работает!
`.testimonials` один единственный в своем роде внутри `.avia-testimonial-wrapper`.

Надо отталкиваться от обертки:

```
.avia-testimonial-wrapper:nth-of-type(odd) .testimonials {
  color: lightgray;   
  font-size: 53px !important;
}
```

Почему срабатывает через `odd` вам надо разобраться самому.

Comment: @VenZell .testimonals:first-child - не работает, .testimonals:last-child - выбирает все три отзыва!